# How to generate Pods folder when adding onesignal-cordova-plugin in Ionic Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, pod-install

I'm adding OneSignal to my Ionic Cordova project, and following [this guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup). In section 3.16 it mentions the `Platforms -> ios -> Pods` folder, but this `Pods` folder doesn't exist. I know that to create the `Pods` folder you have to run `pod install`, but I've never done this in an Ionic Cordova project. Should I navigate to `Platforms/ios` and run `pod install` from there? The reason I ask is that even though in section 2.1 they mention `npm install ionic-cordova-plugin`, they never mention running `pod install`.

Comment: You must have a pods folder under `platforms/ios/Pods`. This folder should be generated during the build process. Have you every built your app for iOS before installing the onesignal plugin ? Or is it a fresh app ?

Comment: I had not built the app for iOS before installing. Does the Pods folder get generated when you build the app for iOS, or just when you run `pod install`?

Comment: The pods folder should be generated at build time if it does not exist. Try building your app just to try and see if it resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing seems rather iffy, as generally, in Cordova projects, the `platform` folder should be under `.gitignore`. The entire guide consists of modifying files that should not be in your repository.

That being said, in order to generate the `Pods` folder, cf. OneSignal's [native iOS SDK guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#step-3---import-the-onesignal-sdk-into-your-xcode-project).

1. Create `Podfile` under `platforms/ios`
2. Copy the contents into `Podfile` from the link provided (change accordingly, e.g. `'your_project_name'`:

```
target 'your_project_name' do
  #only copy below line
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  #only copy below line
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

3. Run `pod install`